# AJAX request duplicate items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using AJAX to "Show More". Currently I have my custom post type show 12 initially and when the "Show More" button is clicked, 12 more `post-types` are loaded on page.

**The Issue:** After the first click, 12 are shown. But every click proceeding, it continues to repeat the previously populated 12 items.

**Question:** How can I properly use AJAX to show the posts, by 12s, when the users clicks "Show More".

**AJAX Handler in Functions.php**

```
function ajax_more_team($offset) {

  $offset = $offset + 12;
  header("Content-Type: text/html");

  $args = array(
      'suppress_filters' => true,
      'post_type'   =>  'team',
      'posts_per_page'  =>  12,
      'offset'  =>  $offset,
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($the_query -> have_posts()) :  while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

          //Loop content            

        endwhile;
     endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  die($out);
}
```

**Jquery Function**

```
var count = 0;

function load_more_team(count) {

    var count = count + 12

    var button = $('#more_posts'),
        data =  {
            'action': 'ajax_more_team',
            'offset': count
        }

    $.ajax({
        url: team_ajax.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.length){
                $("#ajax_posts").append(data);
                button.attr("disabled",false);

            } else{
                button.attr("disabled",true);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('#more_posts').click(function() {
    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    load_more_team();
});
```

## Edit:


To add a bit of extra context, I am adding the initial page template loop.

**page.php**

```
<div id="ajax_posts" class="row">

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' =>  'team',
                'posts_per_page'    =>  12
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

        <?php if($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $id = get_the_id(); ?>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $id ?>">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('employee_headshot'); ?>" alt="<?php the_field('employee_name'); ?>">
                    </a>
                    <div class="team-info">
                        <h6><?php the_field('employee_name'); ?></h6>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <div class="modal-icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/imgs/modal-icon.svg">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="team-close-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php the_field('employee_headshot'); ?>" alt="Alice George">
                                <div class="team-info">
                                    <h6><?php the_field('employee_name'); ?></h6>
                                    <p><strong>Title:<br></strong> <?php the_field('employee_title'); ?></p>
                                    <p><strong>Company:<br></strong> <?php the_field('employee_company'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
        if( $the_query->max_num_pages > 1)
        echo '<div id="more_posts" class="btn-primary mt-4">View More</div>'
    ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need count * 12, not +.

Comment: Print out the value of count after incrementing; if that runs as expected, var_dump $offset at the beginning of your PHP function.

Comment: @TimvanUum no, 0 * 12 = 0

Comment: @TimvanUum Wouldn't that be multiplying the amount? So on first click is 1, 1 * 12 = 12, second click 2, 2 * 12 = 24. Showing 24 elements. I only want to show 12 elements at a time.

Comment: Not sure how you're recieving the $offset value in your PHP function but $offset here should be just the POST value 'offset', no + 12 or anything. That way at first call you have a offset of 0 and get first 12 records starting at row 1, next time you have offset of 12 and get next 12 records (starting at the 13th row). Your post_per_page remain 12, while offset multiplies. Offset indicates from what records it should begin taking the "post_per_page" amount. For javascript part see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to your code, this should work for you. I think count was a bit confusing, cause for me, it wasn't immediatly clear if it was a total amount or the current page.

Not sure how you're recieving the $offset value in your PHP function but $offset here should be just the POST value 'offset', no + 12 or anything. That way at first call you have a offset of 0 and get first 12 records starting at row 1, next time you have offset of 12 and get next 12 records (starting at the 13th row). Your post_per_page remain 12, while offset multiplies. Offset indicates from what records it should begin taking the "post_per_page" amount.

```
function ajax_more_team($offset) {

  $offset = $_POST['offset'];
  header("Content-Type: text/html");

  $args = array(
      'suppress_filters' => true,
      'post_type'   =>  'team',
      'posts_per_page'  =>  12,
      'offset'  =>  $offset,
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($the_query -> have_posts()) :  while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

          //Loop content            

        endwhile;
     endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  die($out);
}
```

-

```
var page = 1; // first page

function load_more_team() {


var button = $('#more_posts'),
    data =  {
        'action': 'ajax_more_team',
        'offset': page * 12 // first time 0 * 12 = offset 0
    }

$.ajax({
    url: team_ajax.ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        if(data.length){
            $("#ajax_posts").append(data);
            button.attr("disabled",false);

        } else{
            button.attr("disabled",true);
        }
        page++; // increment page after first request
    }


});


return false;
}
```

Comment: so you are saying instead of `$offset = $offset + 12;` it should be `$offset = $_POST['offset']` in my functions.php?

Comment: Yes, or if $offset has the right value just use the parameter. Not sure how wordpress handles those things :) $_POST['offset'] should work.

Comment: The initial question I used as reference is here, but no answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77487/ajax-loading-duplicate-post I got to the point where I am now.

Comment: Tim, the code worked after tinkering and a few edits I made. If you could edit the code with the following I will accept the answer. The 1st was the `var page = 0`, It has to be `var page = 1` or else it will return the currently shown 12 and cause duplication. The second is the page increment, currently it is within AJAX request and should be outside it. Otherwise you receive a "Unexpected Identifier" error

Comment: Edited my answer, however 0 should be correct, is it true you have the first 12 already without ajax request? Page increment was outside the success function. Had to be inside, better than outside whole ajax request. This prevents a bit of spamming the button.

Comment: Apologies, I have the 1st twelve post-types shown on my page template via wp_query, set to `posts_per_page => 12`

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: No problems, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = 2; // first page already loaded

function load_more_team() {
var button = $('#more_posts'),
    data =  {
        'action': 'ajax_more_team',
        'paged': page
    }

$.ajax({
    url: team_ajax.ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        if(data.length){
            $("#ajax_posts").append(data);
            button.attr("disabled",false);

        } else{
            button.attr("disabled",true);
        }
        page++; // increment page after request
    }
});
return false;
}

function ajax_more_team() {
  $paged = $_POST['paged'];
  header("Content-Type: text/html");

  $args = array(
      'suppress_filters' => true,
      'post_type'   =>  'team',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'  =>  12,
      'paged'  =>  $paged,
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($the_query -> have_posts()) :  while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

          //Loop content            

        endwhile;
     endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  die($out);
}
```

Comment: Also add post status in page.php

Comment: Using paged parameter is proper way to do this. offset parameter is used to skip posts in a query and paged parameter is used along side posts per page which allows pagination. In current scenario offset does the work for but i recommend using paged parameter